# A shopping cart that lets you pay your customors

Tags: shopping-cart, ubercart, oscommerce

I'm looking for a non-standard feature of a shopping cart:
My partners should be able to preform some actions in my website, and gain money. At a certain point, a partner may whish to cash-out/withdraw the money she has gained to her pay-pal account.

Are you aware of such a reverse shopping cart? Open source solutions are preferred.
Thanks!

P.S.
I'm aware that this is not strictly a programming question. I hope it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a shopping cart is it then?

Do you need the features of a regular shopping cart too?

If not, you really only need to write some code that talks to the PayPal API and tells it to send £X to Y.

Comment: Thanks clocKwize, I don't want to write a CMS from scratch, and yes, I need the features of a regular shopping cart too (creating users, sending them messages, etc.).

Comment: You seem to be getting confused with the difference between a shopping cart and a cms.